# Mapeamento um para zero com entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Boa tarde, tenho uma tabela de documento que possui relacionamento 1 para 0 com outra tabela de `Usuario` para retornar o nome do usuário, porem me é dado o erro:

> Conversão especificada não é válida.

Meu mapeamento:

```
public class DocumentoOffConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentoOff>
{
    public DocumentoOffConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("DOCUMENTO");

        this.Property(x => x.DataCriacao).HasColumnName("DATACRIACAO");
        this.Property(x => x.Enviadoar).HasColumnName("STATUS");
        this.Property(x => x.UsuarioId).HasColumnName("USUARIO_ID");

    }
}
```

Na `View` tento mostrar o seguinte campo:

```
<th>
@(Html.SortingColumn("Fiscal", nameof(Model.Usuario.Nome), 
    "Index", new { Model.Usuario.Nome }, 
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div-gerenciador-auto-termos-index", 
        HttpMethod = "POST" 
    }))
</th>
```

---

```
public UsuarioOffConfiguration()
{
    this.ToTable("USUARIO");

    this.Property(x => x.UsuarioId)
        .HasColumnName("ID");

    HasMany(x => x.Documentos)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Usuario)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UsuarioId);
}
```

porem é me retornado o erro acima mencionado, alguem pode me dar uma luz em como resolver?

Comment: Aonde exatamente dá esse erro? Tem como colocar as duas relações ?

Comment: no momento em que clico no botao consultar para que seja carregada a grid em que é preciso mostrar o Nome do Usuario na grid, esse nome vem do relacionamento de outra tabela, que é o que eu disse, preciso saber como eu faria um relacionamento 1 para zero para retornar o nome do usuario

Comment: Seria mais ou menos assim: http://www.macoratti.net/Cursos/ef_curb1/ef_curb10.htm dá uma olhada nesse link tem o relacionamento 1 para 1 que é o mesmo de 1 para 0 -> Um-para-Um : Aluno e AlunoEndereco possuem uma relacionamento one-to-one, ou seja, Aluno possui zero ou um AlunoEndereco;

Comment: Qual é a suas duas relações é usuario e documento?

Comment: Conversei com um amigo e ele me disse que em relacionamentos 1 para zero não é preciso fazer mapeamento algum, porem o erro continua ocorrendo. Em meu dominio de DOCUMENTO possuo uma propriedade public virtual Usuario Usuario, que é para trazer o nome do usuario para mim, porem ocorre o erro.

Comment: Eu posso exemplificar, só me diga é um usuario e ou nenhum documento?

Comment: coloquei o mapeamento da tabela usuario para vc ver como estou fazendo...

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada agora na sua pergunta, e você postou a parte que realmente interessa em sua última edição e o relacionamento **1** para **1** está muito estranho, no caso da sua pergunta está **1** para **muitos**, `HasMany(x => x.Documentos)` mas, você pode explicar qual é o relacionamento esperado amigo?